# How to create an input box in vue js, that user can manually adjust the href of a button to what writen in the box after submit it

Tags: javascript, vue.js, button, user-input, form-submit

I am a newbie in vue js and having some issue, if anyone can help me out.

I am having 4 buttons (A,B,C,D), which when we clicked on will go to the href linked inside.
I would like to create a config page with 4 input boxes, on those boxes show the actual href of those buttons. When we change the address in the input box and submit the form, it will automatically replace the href of those buttons with new one.

Example: Button A href="google.com"
After we input A ="youtube.com" and submit then A href="youtube.com"

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question. Maybe needs more direction or context? So you're saying you want a user input to direct what the `href` is?

Comment: true, the input will be new href for those buttons after I update it. Its like a setting page for those buttons, which I can easily adjust the links later.

Answer (score 0):

You could try binding the value from the input to the href like so

```
<button :href="inputValue"/>
```

And set the inputValue with the input

```
<input v-model="inputValue" />
```

The colon `:` is shorthand for `v-bind:`

The v-model will set the value on input, if you only want it to set on enter try

```
<input v-model="inputValue.lazy" />
```